# UITableViewCell showing same content in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm trying to implement custom cell in Swift by code. But the cell's content is not getting updated. Am I doing something wrong?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell: MyOrdersViewControllerLatest! = tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? MyOrdersViewControllerLatest

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = MyOrdersViewControllerLatest(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    }

    cell.itemId = nil
    cell.itemName = nil
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to actually set the cell's data to something from your datasource. You're just setting your `itemId` and `itemName` to `nil`.

Comment: I'm configuring the cell using another func call

self.configureCell(&cell, indexPath: indexPath) and in that function I'm setting the cell's value. Say for ex.: cell.itemId = "123" and cell.itemName="Mobile Phone". There is no difference whether I set the cell properties to nill or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tableView.registerClass() solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just set the `itemId` and the `itemName` to `nil` which means, that there is no value. You have to set the value to something which is in your datasource. For example if you have an array an you want to access the arrayelement which equals the row index:

```
cell.itemId = yourArray[indexPath.row].id
cell.itemName = yourArray[indexPath.row].name
return cell
```